# Global aggregation on non-default measure

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

To aggregate along the default measure we use:

```
SELECT FROM [Sales]
```

It returns a "scalar", a value without any header:

```
+------+
| 1000 |
+------+
```

How to do the same with non default measure?

This raises an error:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Quantity] FROM [Sales]
```

This works:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Quantity] ON 0 FROM [Sales]
```

But instead of having a "scalar" we get an additional header with the name of the measure:

```
+----------+
| Quantity |
+----------+
|   1000   |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of query

```
SELECT FROM [Sales]
```

is so called *query with zero axes*. Because no members were assigned to any (non-slicer) axis, the result is considered to have zero axes and by convention would be single
unlabeled cell, or at least cell with no distinct row or column headers, and that is what you see.

With this query

```
SELECT [Measures].[Quantity] ON 0 FROM [Sales]
```

you have specified that you want to see Quantity measure on axes 0 (to see Quantity measure on Columns).

To achieve "zero axes" query result you should put your measure on slicer (specified with Where):

```
SELECT  FROM [Sales]
WHERE [Measures].[Quantity]
```

Comment: Thanks this is it! :) `WHERE` is the last place where I would have put the measure. What is the logic behind this "strange" syntax?

Comment: "MDX WHERE clause reduces the scope of the query. The WHERE clause reduces the cube into a new 'sliced' cube, the slice being defined by the WHERE clause." - Yes, MDX is a little bit strange language, especially if you have previous experience with SQL. Besides SELECT, FROM and WHERE keywords it has nothing to do with SQL. I would recommend you to read "MDX Solutions" or any other MDX specific book to further understand this logic.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the reference book. :)